# Gnuplot: Adding some user data column to the output table?

Tags: macos, unix, gnuplot, gnu

I just want to save some gnuplot-generated data to a data file with help of the 'set table' command. 
The data should be a vector and his length. The vector offset is calculated to any point of an input-file 'filed.dat'.
Printing the vector-data to the file is no problem. I do it this way:

```
splot 'field.dat' using 1:2:3:(-$2):($3):($1):(sqrt(($1)**2+($2)**2+($3)**2)) with vectors;
```

The Output is for example something like that:

```
# x y z delta_x delta_y delta_z type
-2 -3 -4  3 -4 -2 i
-1 -3 -4  3 -4 -1 i
 0 -3 -4  3 -4  0 i
 1 -3 -4  3 -4  1 i
 2 -3 -4  3 -4  2 i
```

But i want to add the calculated vector length to the output file. It should look like this:

```
 # x y z delta_x delta_y delta_z length type
    -2 -3 -4  3 -4 -2 5.39 i
    -1 -3 -4  3 -4 -1 5.10 i
     0 -3 -4  3 -4  0 5.00 i
     1 -3 -4  3 -4  1 5.10 i
     2 -3 -4  3 -4  2 5.39 i
```

Does anyone know how to do it with gnuplot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in gnuplot, because a maximum of six columns is written to the output file (for other plotting styles than `vectors` its less).

However, you could pipe the table output through e.g. `awk` to add this information:

```
set output '| awk ''{\
  if (!match($1, "^#") && length()) {\
      print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, sqrt($4**2 + $5**2 + $6**2), $7\
  } else {\
      print $0}\
  }'' > field-out.dat'
set table
splot 'field.dat' using 1:2:3:(-$2):3:1 with vectors
unset table
```

You must use `set output` in order to use the pipe, `set table "| ..."` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

**Just as an update:**
gnuplot 5.0 introduced the plotting style `with table` (check `help with table`).
With this you can plot max. 14 columns to a file (or datablock).
So, basically you should be able to plot any string formatted via `sprintf()` and hence more than 14 columns to a file (check `help sprintf`),
however, for some reason this works only from gnuplot 5.2.0 on. Hence, with 5.2.0 you can also use the format specifiers to "shape" the output format as you like (check `help format_specifiers`).

By the way, shouldn't be the length of the vector `sqrt(($4)**2 + ($5)**2 + ($6)**2)`?  Anyhow.

**Data:** `SO19465644.dat`

```
# x y z delta_x delta_y delta_z type
-2 -3 -4  3 -4 -2
-1 -3 -4  3 -4 -1
 0 -3 -4  3 -4  0
 1 -3 -4  3 -4  1
 2 -3 -4  3 -4  2
```

**Script 1:** (works for gnuplot>=5.2.0, Sept. 2017)

```
### write formatted data to a file
reset session

FILE     = "SO19465644.dat"
FILE_OUT = "SO19465644_V52_out.dat"

set table FILE_OUT
    plot FILE u (sprintf("% 3g % 3g % 3g % 3g % 3g % 3g % 10.6f",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,(sqrt(($1)**2+($2)**2+($3)**2)))) w table
unset table

plot FILE_OUT u 1:7 w lp pt 7
### end of script
```

**Output file 1:** `SO19465644_V52_out.dat`

```
  -2  -3  -4   3  -4  -2   5.385165
  -1  -3  -4   3  -4  -1   5.099020
   0  -3  -4   3  -4   0   5.000000
   1  -3  -4   3  -4   1   5.099020
   2  -3  -4   3  -4   2   5.385165
```

**Script 2:** (works for gnuplot>=5.0.0, Jan. 2015)

```
### write up to 14 columns to a file (gnuplot>=5.0.0)
reset session

FILE     = "SO19465644.dat"
FILE_OUT = "SO19465644_V50_out.dat"

set table FILE_OUT
    plot FILE u 1:2:3:4:5:6:(sqrt(($1)**2+($2)**2+($3)**2)) w table
unset table

plot FILE_OUT u 1:7 w lp pt 7
### end of script
```

**Output file 2:** `SO19465644_V50.dat`

```
 -2 -3 -4 3 -4 -2 5.38516
 -1 -3 -4 3 -4 -1 5.09902
 0 -3 -4 3 -4 0 5
 1 -3 -4 3 -4 1 5.09902
 2 -3 -4 3 -4 2 5.38516
```

And just for fun, a "retro"-workaround for older versions without using external tools like awk, etc., hence platform-independent.
Actually, you can write more than 6 or even 14 output "columns" if you use `with labels`. However, then the 3rd column is a string enclosed in `""`, and you have to do a little extra operation when you want to plot that file. I'm not sure if there is a length limit for the label, I checked only up to 500 characters.

**Script 3:** (works with gnuplot 4.4.0, March 2010)

```
### write more than 6 columns to a file (gnuplot>=4.4.0)
reset

FILE     = "SO19465644.dat"
FILE_OUT = "SO19465644_V44_out.dat"

set table FILE_OUT
    plot FILE u 1:2:(sprintf(" %g %g %g %g %g",$3,$4,$5,$6,(sqrt(($1)**2+($2)**2+($3)**2)))) w labels notitle
unset table

myCol(i) = i>2 ? real(word(strcol(3),i-2)) : column(i)

plot FILE_OUT u 1:(myCol(7)) w lp pt 7
### end of script
```

**Output file 3:** `SO19465644_V44_out.dat`

```
# Curve 0 of 1, 5 points
# x y label type
-2 -3  " -4 3 -4 -2 5.38516"
-1 -3  " -4 3 -4 -1 5.09902"
 0 -3  " -4 3 -4 0 5"
 1 -3  " -4 3 -4 1 5.09902"
 2 -3  " -4 3 -4 2 5.38516"
```

**Result:**

[image]